# How do I gloss a Semitic verb?

Tags: morphology, arabic, semitic-languages, roots, interlinear-gloss

"Standard" glossing (following [the Leipzig rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php)) uses a linear model of breaking down words into morphemes. In other words, it assumes you can draw lines between all the morphemes to separate them.

But what do I do when these assumptions break down?

For example, the Arabic word كتب (*kataba*) means "he wrote". It consists of two morphemes: the root *k-t-b* means "write", and the pattern *_a_a_a* means "3.M.SG.PERF".

I could gloss this following Rule 8:

> *k-a-t-a-b-a*
>   write-3.M.SG.PERF-write-3.M.SG.PERF-write-3.M.SG.PERF

Or following Rule 9:

> k<a>t<a>b<a>
>   write<3.M.SG.PERF>

Or following the optional Rule 4D:

> kataba
>   3.M.SG.PERF/write

But none of these seems particularly satisfying. What is actually used "in the wild", and what do linguists find most useful when they're trying to actually study a Semitic language?

Comment: This feature is not proper to Semitic language. I suggest to widen your question to all languages with nonconcatenative morphology. Besides, you only point out the case of transfixation, what about gemination, reduplication, ...

Comment: @amegnunsen Entirely fair; however, the Leipzig rules already cover other types of non-concatenative morphology (such as tone-only morphemes and reduplication). Semitic verbs were the one type I know about that isn't covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking at the 2020 book *The NP-strategy for Expressing Reciprocity* by Elitzur Bar-Asher Siegal, so to answer your question what is used in the wild with but one example: this author simply does (p. 47, for Biblical Hebrew):

> *yiddōr*
>   vow.IPF.3.M.SG

> *yidḥāqû*
>   prod.IPF.3.M.PL

When I want to break it down further, I use angular brackets to distinguish prefix conjugation from root and stem:

> *y<idḥāq>û*
>   IPF.M.3PL<prod\G>

But because angular brackets are normally for infices rather than circumfices this needs to be explained in a footnote or introduction. (G here refers to the basic stem/binyan.)

For suffix conjugations I don't use angular brackets:

> *katab-a*
>   write\G.PFV-M.3SG